# Remove custom numbers from string in php

Tags: php, string, replace

I have some strings like

```
$str1 = "Audi-TT-RS-2012-widescreen-77.jpg";
$str2 = "Audi-R8-widescreen-039.jpg";
$str3 = "2008-bmw-6-series-front-and-side.jpg";
$str4 = "Opel_tigra_2-doors-21313.jpg"; //where 21313 is an id that want to be removed also.
```

I want to make a function that will remove all numbers except year, and the car "model".
I don't know how exactly to detect if the number is a year, or a model number or an id.
Thank you

Comment: is the id always before the *.jpg* ? and after the last hyphen?

Comment: Some research goes a long way.

Comment: before attempting to create this function , first you must have a standard naming of your files. or you will need to create a very complex function

Comment: good with with the cars too many model available!

Comment: the only pattern i can find is, if within string if two instances of number are found then only 1st one holds the model number but rest can be eliminated

Comment: Before you can write a regular expression, you have to be able to describe, in English, the rules that you're trying to implement.

Comment: @Dragonsome will have some will not have id numbers.

Comment: @tomexsans the file naming is "random"

Comment: some things require a human, just did a project where a student was hired to match 40k data sets, software provided best guess, but human need in the loop

Comment: Are all the years in full years (4 digits)?

Comment: Well, if the naming is "random" then you'll have to create a function to remove "random" numbers and hope you're veeeeeeeeery lucky... ;/ Or at least help the people trying to help you by giving more (accurate) info...

Comment: @Antony the year is 4 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str1 = "Audi-TT-RS-2012-widescreen-77.jpg";
$str2 = "Audi-R8-widescreen-039.jpg";
$str3 = "2008-bmw-6-series-front-and-side.jpg";
$str4 = "Opel_tigra_2-doors-21313.jpg";
$strs = array($str1, $str2, $str3, $str4);
foreach ($strs as $str) {
    preg_match_all('/(?<!\d)(\d{4})(?!\d)\-*/', $str, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $year) {
        if (abs($year - date("Y")) < 100) {
            // this is within 100 years
        }
    }
}
```

Removing numbers

```
$str1 = "Audi-TT-RS-2012-widescreen-77.jpg";
$str2 = "Audi-R8-widescreen-039.jpg";
$str3 = "2008-bmw-6-series-front-and-side.jpg";
$str4 = "Opel_tigra_2-doors-21313.jpg";
$strs = array($str1, $str2, $str3, $str4);
foreach ($strs as $str) {
    preg_match_all('/(?<!\d)(\d{4})(?!\d)\-*/', $str, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $year) {
        if (abs($year - date("Y")) < 100) {
            $str =  preg_replace('/(?<!\d)(\d{4})(?!\d)/', '[year]', $str);
        }
    }
    preg_match_all('/(?<!\d)(\d{1})(?!\d)\-*/', $str, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $model) {
        $str =  preg_replace('/(?<!\d)(\d{1})(?!\d)/', '[model]', $str);
    }

    preg_match_all('/\-*(\d+)\-*/', $str, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $id) {
        $str =  preg_replace('/\-*(\d+)\-*/', '', $str);
    }
    $str =  preg_replace('/\[year\]/', $year, $str);
    $str =  preg_replace('/\[model\]/', $model, $str);
    echo $str."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could remove all the 4-digit numbers starting with 19 and 20 (only 20 if cars aren't older than 2000) and the number before the last dot in the string (if any)... but who knows if it will be 100% accurate with the info you provided (lack of naming pattern).